# Do we need the semaphore when one task is writing to the variable and other tasks reading that variable?

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, esp32, freertos

I am working on freeRtos, and I have a variable called say x. Now one and only one  task is writing to this variable per second and other tasks are reading the variable value. Do I need to guard the variable with mutex?

Comment: Well, if the size/location of var spans read cycles...  Anyway may need a memory barrier if multicore.  Definitely don't need a semaphore to ensure integrity, though you might use one to signal a waiting thread of an update.

Comment: I presume you mean specifically a _mutex_ semaphore rather than a regular semaphore.  In FreeRTOS mutexes are a type of semaphore, and part of the semaphore API.  Most operating systems have distinct APIs for mutexes and semaphores, and do not conflate the two.  FreeRTOS is just weird like that - a hobby project gone unfortunately viral.

Comment: Mutex not needed in this case, but make sure the variable is `volatile`.

Answer (score 5):

If the variable is 32 bits or smaller, and its value stands alone and is not to be interpreted with regard to any other variable, then you do not need a mutex.

If you have one data item bigger than 32 bits, or else you have multiple items that have to stay together (eg: a light sensor that records both brightness and colour) then you need a mutex so that the readers can't get part of the old data and part of the new data.

Comment: That is assuming you are using a microcontroller that can read 32-bit objects atomically.  FreeRTOS is also used on 8-bit and 16-bit devices, and the size of the variable you can use safely without a mutex is then correspondingly smaller.

Comment: @David the question is tagged esp32, so yes this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s good practice using a mutex semaphore while changing and reading variables, used in multiple tasks.

Multibyte variables like strings could be changed while reading in another task. It will not be done every readout, but depending on the frequency the likelihood it will is much higher.

NB: writing to 32bit or smaller variables can be safe, IF accessed by tasks on the same core (if a duo core esp is used)

Comment: I don't think you are correct that multiple cores means a mutex is needed.  An atomic access is atomic for all bus masters, you always get either the old data or the new data.  Caching may mean you get the old data for a moment longer than otherwise, but a mutex is overkill to prevent that (if it even matters) you just need a flush or barrier instruction.

Comment: You are right, for his case it’s not a problem.  But I can imagine it’s tricky when like two or more variables are read/written and they have some coherence (not necessary in a struct).

Comment: Again - the size of the variable you can access atomically is dependent on the processor.  32-bit is a common size for modern microcontrollers, but some 32-bit devices can handle 64-bit atomic accesses, and FreeRTOS can be used with devices that have smaller atomic sizes.

Comment: Remember, mutexes are expensive - the run-time cost can be significant, and they require ram for their task queues.  Using a mutex "because a variable is used in more than one task" is /not/ an alternative to thinking about the case and picking a correct solution.

Comment: Mutexes are expensive, but freertos also. Sometimes it’s better to just use a looped structures, atomic or not will then loose it’s point.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use mutex , consider this case:(r for read pro, w for write p ro)

if r is called before w, but due to the deployment, w finishes changing the value before r reads the value. This makes a trouble, r reads the new vlaue but if expects the old value.