# On STM32L476, should I still use a mutex to guard a single byte variable if ARMv7-M guarantees single-copy atomicity for byte length variables?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, freertos, cortex-m

I am using an STM32L476 with CMSIS OS2 which implements FreeRTOS v10.3.1.

The L4 is a Cortex-M4 MCU which implements ARMv7E-M architecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M

The difference between ARMv7E-M and ARMv7-M is that ARMv7E-M implements DSP which I do not use in my application. This effectively makes the L4 a ARMv7-M: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest (Page A1-22).

ARMv7-M has single byte atomicity from the ARM reference manual: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest (Page A3-80).

With these ideas in mind, should I still use a mutex for variables which are 8-bits in length?

There are other answers on the site related to 32-bit variables and non ARM Cortex M4 specific applications but I am looking for this specific scenario.

I am expecting to not use a mutex for uint8_t and int8_t variable types but I would like to confirm.

Comment: What C version are you using?  I imagine if you are unsure, you could use `atomic_load/store` if you are using C11.  I imagine if the target has single byte atomicity, then it would get optimized out.

Comment: No, you do not need a mutex if the 8 bit variable stands alone.  I'm inclined to mark your question as a duplicate of this one unless you think it adds anything specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582911/do-we-need-the-semaphore-when-one-task-is-writing-to-the-variable-and-other-task/72584213#72584213

Comment: On arm, the `stdatomic.h` functions, IIRC, will do a flush of the cache line so that other CPUs will "see" the updated value immediately (e.g. arm `dmb` instruction). So, you may want `atomic_*` functions

Comment: @CraigEstey what cache? L4 does not have one except the ART.

Comment: @0___________ I guess I should have said that the atomics functions will "do the right thing" (_whatever_ that is for a given arch). However, section A3.5.2 of the linked manual (for armv7-m) uses the word "cacheable" along with A3.5.2-A3.5.5 about memory models and types of memory, etc.

Comment: @CraigEstey because it is general architecture documentation. Manufacturers do not implement everything. L4 series is designed for energy efficiency and have quite slow clocks and does not need a cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMW operations are not atomic.

So simple reading and writing don't require any form of protection.

If you modify the 8bit variable and want the whole operation to be atomic - it will require special instructions or mutexes.

Comment: I am trying to just ensure that a single read or a single write is atomic. Based on the provided documentation, is that what you're saying on your second line?

Comment: @tom.nowak Writes and reads are atomic